# Python regex - Find multiple characters in a substring

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, regex-group

```
print 'cycle' ;While i in range(1,n) [[print "Number:" ;print i; print 'and,']]
```

I have a line like this for example. I want to extract the semicolon characters only from the [[ ... ]] substring, inside the double square brackets.

If I use `re.search(\[\[.*(\s*;).*\]\])` I get only one semicolon. Is there a proper solution for this?

Comment: No there isn't a really good regex solution, but `;(?=(?:(?!\[\[).)*\]\])` might work well enough.

Comment: Could you please provide a brief explanation how does this work?

Comment: Rather than using regex to attempt to match each semicolon-delimited group inside [[ ]], you might find it easier and more robust to use regex to extract everything inside [[ ]], then split that capture on a semicolon. That will avoid the problems of the accepted solution matching when it shouldn't!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex is never a great choice for things like this because it's very easy to trip up, but the following pattern works in *trivial cases*:

```
;(?=(?:(?!\[\[).)*\]\])
```

---

Pattern breakdown:

```
;                # match literal ";"
(?=              # lookahead assertion: assert the following pattern matches:
    (?:          
        (?!\[\[) # as long as we don't find a "[["...
        .        # ...consume the next character
    )*           # ...as often as necessary
    \]\]         # until we find "]]"
)
```

In other words, the pattern checks if a semicolon is followed by `]]`, but not followed by `[[`.

---

Examples of strings where the pattern won't work:

- `; ]]` (will match)
- `[[ ; "this is text [[" ]]` (won't match)